# Update Device enrollment details in Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can you update the existing devices which are enrolled to a MobileFirst server by adding user id? Below is the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

User Id will be set only if your client goes through the Authentication flow with any valid user security realm.

However you can set friendly name for the clients using `setFriendlyName` API. You can find more information about the API in the MFP 7.1 documentation.

For Cordova : [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html?view=kc#setFriendlyName)

For Android : [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLClient.html?view=kc#setFriendlyName(java.lang.String,%20com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResponseListener))

For iOS : [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/Classes/WLClient.html?view=kc#//api/name/setFriendlyName:withCompletionHandler:)

Answer (score 0):

This API (setFriendlyName) is currently not available in the Android or iOS client SDKs. It was added in the November '16 update, but removed in December '16 update. As of now it is only available in the JS client SDK.

The documentation for the Native SDKs still show this API as available, which I suspect means that this will reappear in the near future.

Comment: The May '17 client SDK patch now has this functionality enabled again..